# Metadata language

Tags: metadata-api

I have a simple question. I was wondering what determines the language of the metadata that is being retrieved. For example, let's say I have org 1 where when I retrieve all of its layouts I see CaseInteraction-Case Feed Layout.layout as one of the layouts retrieved.

For org 2, when I retrieve all of its layouts, I see a layout with the name CaseInteraction-个案摘要布局.layout

So I was wondering why Salesforce output the same layout (I'm assuming) but in different languages. CaseInteraction is an interesting one as that seems like it is a Salesforce managed layout, so we do not have control over it.

I was wondering if it's because the two orgs are in different pods. One org is in a pod in the Japan region, the other is in America's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I was wondering if it's because the two orgs are in different pods. One org is in a pod in the Japan region, the other is in America's.

Pretty nearly, yeah - the org's language. The language of the org is set when it's created - if it's a scratch org, for example, it can be set as `language` in the org definition file, or will take the default language of its `country`, if any, or the language of its Dev Hub.

Metadata items that are user-visible may be localized into the org language, depending upon which language that is (not all languages have the same level of localization). Page Layout names are user-visible, hence their translation here into Japanese.